# Access Service layer property in Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn SpEL to inject a property in controller which is inside service layer. The output is however always null.

This is my controller class.

```
@RestController
@Validated
 public class RestApp1 implements CONSTANTS, ApplicationContextAware {

@Value("dummy String 3")
String value3;

@Value("#{@dummyServiceLayer.dbProperty}")
String value4;

@Autowired
DummyServiceLayer dummyLayer;

public ApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;


@GetMapping("/dummyGet")
public ResponseEntity<?> getMethodDummy() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("value 3 is : " + value3);
    System.out.println("value 4 is : " + dummyLayer.dbProperty);
        dummyLayer.doingDBstuff();

    return new ResponseEntity("Api Completed", HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

This is service layer class

```
@Service
 public class DummyServiceLayer {

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplateMaster;

@Value("#{dummyLayer2.getDbProperty('dummyString')}")
public String dbProperty;

@Value("some value")
public String dbProperty1;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Async("asyncTaskWorkerPool")
public void doingDBstuff() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("object hash : "+this);
        System.out.println("DB property fetched using spring expression library        +"+dbProperty);


}
}
```

The output is like this:
value 3 is : dummy String 3
value 4 is : null

When i debugged the application it seems like when the service layer is called then some proxy object is substituted which contains the correct values.

Can anyone explain why value4 is always null in controller. Tried everything didn't help.

Comment: and how does your property file look like?

Comment: @Pavel i am reading any value from property file apart from db configuration. All values are hard coded as of now for testing.